# Mark Haxe Class for forced extend?

Tags: class, inheritance, haxe

Is there a compiler meta for Class declaration, that **prevents creating Class instance** before extending it? In other words - some sort of opposite of `@:final` meta.

Like so (last line of code):

```
class A {
    // ...
}

class B extends A {
    // ...
}

// ...
var b = new B(); // OK
var a = new A(); // induce compiler-error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the other answers are correct (no constructor or private constructor), but there are a few more details that you may interest you:

- Here's [an example](https://try.haxe.org/#387Bb) of no constructor. Of note is that `A` simply doesn't have a constructor, and `B` simply doesn't call `super()`. Other than that, everything else works as you'd expect.
- Here's [an example](https://try.haxe.org/#Ec9CF) of a private constructor. You still can't instantiate a `new A()`, but you do still need to call `super()` from `B`'s constructor.

***Technicalities:***

- Use of some features (like a default value on a member variable) will cause `A` to get an implicit constructor, automatically. Don't worry, this doesn't affect constructability or whether you need to call `super()`. But know that it is there, and if necessary an implicit `super()` call is prepended to `B`'s constructor. See the JS output to verify this.
- In any case, know that you can still instantiate an `A` at runtime with `var a = Type.createInstance(A,[]);` as compile-time type checks do not limit [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

***Related discussion:***

Aside from private/no constructor, Haxe doesn't have a formal notion of **abstract classes**<sup>1</sup> (base classes not expected to be instantiated) or **abstract methods**<sup>2</sup> (functions on abstract base classes with no implementation that *must* be implemented by a derived class.) However, Andy Li wrote [a macro](https://gist.github.com/andyli/5011520) for enforcing some of those concepts if you use them. Such a macro can detect violations of these rules and throw compile-time errors.

---

<sub>1. Not to be confused with [Haxe abstracts types](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html), which are an entirely different topic.</sub>

<sub>2. Not to be confused with **virtual functions**, which wikipedia [describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) as a function which *can* be overridden (though various docs for various languages describe this highly loaded term differently.)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Simply don't declare a constructor at all for class A

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is to create private Class constructor:

```
class A {
    private function new() {
        // ...
    }
}

// ...
var a = new A(); // Error: Cannot access private constructor
```